# Krishna's childhood connection with Repalle village

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I had believed that Sri Krishna's childhood was spent in a remote village Repalle in Andhra Pradesh near Krishna river as per Bhagavata purana. Vasudeva left him there after an arduous journey fearing danger from his uncle Kamsa at Mathura.

Even today there is a [Folklore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZI7AZlxe-Y) deep rooted connection.

However I also know about Puranic references to his spending childhood in Vrindavan not far from Mathura where Kamsa could easily find him.

What may be basis of this Repalle connection of Krishna which is  most definitely there?

Comment: "Repalle (near Vijayawada in present day Andhra Pradesh)"-- it should be Gokula (near Mathura)..and rest of his lilas are also believed in Brija region like Nandganva, Vrindavana, Goverdhan..